# how can I make the click event be executed first before the focusout event is executed?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Basically in a real example of my code I have this problem:
when i start typing in a `text field`, it is shown a modal (in my case a div) and i want that when I click on this `div`, i want the click event to be executed.
The idea is that this `div` disappears when I click outside the text field.

I understand that first the `@focusout` is executed when I click outside of the input search, before the `@click` event is executed.

How can I fix this? in my web page I can have several other HTML elements and when the user clicks on any other element I need the `@focusout` to be executed when previously typed in the text field and not would be a good practice put in each element different to my input text a `myInputText.blur()` event for example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    clickEvent() {
      console.log('click');
    },
    blurEvent() {
      console.log('focusout');
      this.myText="";
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myText: ''
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div class="hello">
      <input  v-model="myText" @focusout="blurEvent" placeholder="write something">
      <div style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red; position:fixed; right:50%; top:0px;" v-if="myText"       @click="clickEvent">Select on option</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear, maybe this will help:  When you open the dialog, add a class to the input that you don't want the blur event, then, when you close the dialog remove the class.  Check for the class in `blur` handler.

Comment: @freedomn-m the user does not necessarily have to close the dialog by clicking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focusout event can tell you the new element that receives focus. If the new focused element is the modal, you can make it optional to run your `blurEvent()` code. The only problem is that div's are not naturally focusable, so they won't be found in your focus event, but you can fix that by adding the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) property to the div.

```html
<div class="hello">
  <input v-model="myText" @focusout="blurEvent" placeholder="write something" />
  <div
    class="my-modal"
    style="cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid red; position: fixed; right: 50%; top: 0px"
    v-if="myText"
    @click="clickEvent"
    tabindex="0" 
  >
    Select on option
  </div>
</div>
```

You will then receive the div element and its properties on the focusout event's [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) property. You can check for some div property like classname to verify the newly focused element is the modal, and conditionally run the rest of the method's code based on the result.

```js
blurEvent(e) {
  console.log('focusout', e);
  if (!e.relatedTarget || e.relatedTarget.className !== 'my-modal') {
    this.myText = '';
  }
}
```